# change the index name of an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I the following code that fetches data from the database

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM vendor where subserviceid='".$subserviceid."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)  
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $finalvendorid[]=$row;
            }
        echo "<pre>";   
        print_r($finalvendorid);
        echo "</pre>";      
    }
```

The array that i get from the above code is like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
        )

)
```

Can anyone tell how i can change this array so that i get the above array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [vendorid] => 9
        )

)
```

Comment: Change "SELECT id" to "SELECT id AS vendorid"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
SELECT id FROM vendor where subser...
```

to:

```
SELECT id AS vendorid FROM vendor where subser...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use alias in other words AS

select vendor as vendorid from table vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change it in your SQL request with **AS**:

```
$sql = "SELECT id AS 'vendorid' FROM [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to go through query change as other answers suggesting , alternative solution may be as

```
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $finalvendorid[]=array("vendorid"=>$row['id']);
            }
```